# Uncaught TypeError: $A.g.lg is not a function - intermittent error on browser back/forward?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I'm seeing a very intermittent error sometimes in my Lightning app.  This is a standalone app, not part of Lightning Experience or Salesforce1.

It's a single-page type of app, so there's not really browser back/forward support.  However, if there is a browser back/forward operation (hitting those buttons in browser or doing a mouse gesture, etc), sometimes I'll see the following error on screen:

```
Sorry to interrupt
Uncaught TypeError: $A.g.lg is not a function
throws at https://(company name)--pc1.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/(long random characters)/aura_prod.js:668:413
```

I also see the following in the console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $$safe-eval$$
at Function.defineProperties (<anonymous>)
at VM17932_safeEval.html:88
at VM17932_safeEval.html:149
```

It's very intermittent, I can't seem to reproduce it at will or figure out what's triggering it.  I tried searching here and Googling it, but I don't see any similar errors out there.  We don't have premier support with Salesforce, so I can't open a bug.

Has anybody seen anything similar or know what it might be?  I've never seen it during normal operation of the app, only during browser back/forward operation (which I know is happening because Chrome on Mac has those shaded arrows that show up on the sides of the screen, at least when it's a mouse gesture that initiated the operation).

Maybe it's trying to reload the page and it's interfering with loading scripts?  My app does use jQuery and DataTables, but I've seen this error occur even when no child components have been created which use those.

Comment: My first guess would be the loading sequence of the scripts. Make sure they are in order of the dependency, i.e required scripts first and then the dependent scripts. Second thing would be to check if within the script you have declared functions and properties before they are used. We recently had an investigation with a customer using jQuery ready() event. A function required by ready() was declared after the ready() call.

Comment: The third thing is, if you are loading scripts using ltng:require, use afterScriptsLoaded handler to run any routines that depend on ALL the script being loaded If those don't work out, please create a git gist of your component bundle and we can take a look.